# Is there a way to inform PageSpeed that our homepage has loaded without waiting for scroll hint on mobile?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

[Our homepage](https://9f49146bae10413426.temporary.link/) is scoring poorly in PageSpeed mobile, apparently because it is waiting for our scroll hint as part of the largest contentful paint.  Oddly it doesn't do this on desktop with a slightly different hint.  We typically get a score of 95 on desktop but only 50 on mobile for the same page, and I believe it is because of this.

Is there anything that can be done to cue PageSpeed that the page is painted once the full-screen image goes up, and to not wait for the scroll hint?

I have tried a variety of cache and minification setting with no joy.  I think the Mobile vs. Desktop images below tell the story:

**MOBILE**
[Mobile Progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdwpZ.png)

**DESKTOP**
[Desktop Progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ouwu.png)

Thanks!